# Testing Flask app.config

Tags: python, flask, nosetests

I am trying to test the configuration of my app, I need to set a flag if `app.config['TEST']` is `True`

Here's the configuration part of my app

```
app.config['TEST'] = False
if app.config['TEST']:
    app.config['FOO'] = 'bar'
else:
    app.config['FOO'] = 'baz'
```

Here's the testcase that is failing:

```
class TestConfigCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app.app.config['TESTING'] = True
        self.app = app.app.test_client()

    def testConfig(self):
        assert 'bar' in self.app.config['FOO']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the beginning you have `TEST` and then you are writing `TESTING`.